# Mvc 3 application stops randomly (especially after recycle) IIS 7.5 Integrated mode

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, integrated-pipeline-mode

we have an MVC 3 application which works under IIS 7 and application pool Managed Pipeline Mode is **Integrated**.

This application suddenly become unstable which means gives error like below.

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        ASP.NET 4.0.30319.0
Date:          04.02.2014 12:01:16
Event ID:      1309
Task Category: Web Event
Level:         Warning
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      
Description:
Event code: 3005 
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
Event time: 04.02.2014 12:01:16 
Event time (UTC): 04.02.2014 10:01:16 
Event ID: 9896973154a54e5b88e6f1799922e853 
Event sequence: 6 
Event occurrence: 1 
Event detail code: 0 

Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/3/ROOT-1-130359816693915362 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: / 
    Application Path: D:\WebSites\ 
    Machine name: DC1VMCIFWEB02 

Process information: 
    Process ID: 4152 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM 

Exception information: 
    Exception type: NullReferenceException 
    Exception message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at System.Web.PipelineModuleStepContainer.GetEventCount(RequestNotification notification, Boolean isPostEvent)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb)
   at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context)
```

Also this is our global.asax.cs code and i was wondering that anything wrong with this code;

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );

        }

        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(); 
        }

        protected void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(0));
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(true);


            if (HttpContext.Current.Session != null)
            {
                CultureInfo ci = (CultureInfo)this.Session["Culture"];
                if (ci == null)
                {
                    string langName = "tr";

                    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.UserLanguages != null && HttpContext.Current.Request.UserLanguages.Length != 0)
                    {
                        langName = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserLanguages[0].Substring(0, 2);
                    }
                    ci = new CultureInfo(langName);
                    this.Session["Culture"] = ci;
                }
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(ci.Name);
            }
        }

        protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();

            Application[HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress.ToString()] = ex;

            Class.LogClass.Error(this.GetType().ToString(), "Application_Error : ", ex);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding this line:

```
Application[HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress.ToString()] = ex;
```

Per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/94xkskdf%28v=vs.140%29.aspx):

> Application state is stored in memory on the server, so **a large amount of data in application state can fill up server memory quickly**. If the application is restarted, application state data is lost. Application state is not shared between multiple servers within a Web farm or between worker processes in a Web garden. Finally, application state is free-threaded, so any data that is stored in application state must have built-in synchronization support. For more information about these considerations, see ASP.NET Application State Overview and ASP.NET State Management Recommendations.

Basically, you are storing a list of global variables that are `UserHostAddress`/`Exception object` maps. Essentially, this is the last error for every IP address who visited the site since the last application pool recycle. Since this state is only wiped out when the application pool recycles, it will act like a slow memory leak. The longer your application pool timeout, and the more likely a user gets an exception somewhere, the more likely you will run the server out of memory.

It is unclear why you are putting the exception into a persistent location, but if your intent is to allow the current request to be able to show the exception a better choice would be to store it in `HttpContext.Items`, which will only last the lifetime of the current request. This will ensure that application errors don't eventually run the server out of memory.

I don't know for certain this is what is causing your application to be unstable, but it is a good place to start.